# Java Method call in anonymous classes

Tags: java, class, methods, treeview

I have a question concerning this code (copied out of java2s.com):

```
  private TreeItem<File> createNode(final File f) {
    return new TreeItem<File>(f) {
      private boolean isLeaf;
      private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
      private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;

      @Override
      public ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> getChildren() {
        super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren(this));
        return super.getChildren();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isLeaf() {
        return isLeaf;
      }

      private ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> buildChildren(
          TreeItem<File> TreeItem) {
        File f = TreeItem.getValue();
        if (f == null) {
          return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
        }
        if (f.isFile()) {
          return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
        }
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
          ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> children = FXCollections
              .observableArrayList();
          for (File childFile : files) {
            children.add(createNode(childFile));
          }
          return children;
        }
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 300, 300);
    VBox vbox = new VBox();

    TreeItem<File> root = createNode(new File("c:/"));
    TreeView treeView = new TreeView<File>(root);

    vbox.getChildren().add(treeView);
    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

I don't really understand why, for example, the "buildChildren" method is called.
Because none of the methods of the TreeItem-anonymousclass is ever invoked in the 
"start" function. There is just an invoke of the method "createNode" initializing the TreeItem.

Best regards 
Steve

Comment: I strongly suspect that `getChildren()` is called by one of those methods. Have you tried debugging the code to find out?

Comment: `super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren(this));` - this method calls `buildChildren`, so I assume it is invoked by either `vbox.getChildren().add(treeView);` or `((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(vbox);`.

Comment: buildChildren is sub method called in createNode Method which eventually used in start method. Debug the code starting from start method to visualize the code flow.

Comment: For completeness, this is the [link of the code on Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Createthetreeitemonthefly.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you provide, `buildChildren(..)` is only called from `getChildren()`. Since this method is overriding a method from a super class we can consult the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#getChildren()) of the super class:

> `public ObservableList<TreeItem<T>> getChildren()`
>
> The children of this TreeItem. This method is called frequently, and it is therefore recommended that the returned list be cached by any TreeItem implementations.
>
> **Returns**:
>   a list that contains the child TreeItems belonging to the TreeItem.

This gives a clue about the fact that this method is called by the JavaFX library that the code uses.

If you want to know when exactly this method is called you can set a breakpoint at the `getChildren()` method using a debugger. When running this code in Eclipse I found that `getChildren()` is first called when clicking to expand the root `TreeItem` in the GUI. The debugger view shows that `buildChildren()` is indeed called by `getChildren()` which in turn is called by other code in `TreeItem`:

[image: call stack for getChildren]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it was really helpfull! And i meant "getChildren" method not the "buildChildren" but you provided me the solution! :) Cheers!